# Program saves a file but does not delete old file with same name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-io

I'm having a problem with a file updating portion of an ASP.NET MVC program I'm working on. The basic premise is that the program will take an edited image from the user, and then update the old file with the new data, keeping the old name. But for some reason, when the file is moved from the temp folder to the folder it's supposed to go to, it's saved as a new file, while keeping the old one. (For example, "foo 1-1.jpg" and "foo 1-1.jpg" exist in the same folder). As far as I can tell, the two filenames are identical. Why is this happening, and how do I make it so that it will delete the old file first, as intended?

I'm getting the old filename before moving it, so there shouldn't be a problem there. There are also no path issues, either.

I'm unsure if there is a problem with the path I'm passing in, but I use the same methodology for getting the filepath to move to, so I don't know why it would fail for File.Delete() and not File.Move().

Here is the code in question:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Move a number of files to a single directory, keeping their names
    /// and overwriting if the switch is toggled.
    /// Will ignore nonexistent files, and return false if the specified directory does not exist.
    /// Returns true if it succeeded, false if it did not.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filePaths">An array of filepath strings, </param>
    /// <param name="saveDirectory">The path to the directory to use</param>
    /// <param name="overWrite">Optional, defaults to false. Whether or not 
    /// to overwrite any existing files with the same name in the new directory. 
    /// If false, skips files that already exist in destination.</param>
    /// <returns>bool</returns>
    public static bool MoveSpecificFiles(string[] filePaths, string saveDirectory, bool overWrite = false)
    {
        //If the directory doesn't exist, error out.
        if (!Directory.Exists(saveDirectory))
        {
            return false;
        }
        string fileName;

        try
        {
            foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
            {
                //Check if the file to be moved exists. If it doesn't, skip it and go to the next one.
                if (File.Exists(filePath))
                {
                    fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

                    //if the overwrite flag is set to true and the file exists in the new directory, delete it.
                    if (overWrite && File.Exists(saveDirectory + fileName))
                    {
                        //WHERE THE ERROR IS OCCURING
                        File.Delete(saveDirectory + fileName);
                    }
                    //If the file to be moved does not exist in the new location, move it there.
                    //This means that duplicate files will not be moved.
                    if (!File.Exists(saveDirectory + fileName))
                    {
                        File.Move(filePath, saveDirectory + fileName);
                    }
                }
                //throw new ArgumentException();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //check = saveDirectory + " " + Path.GetFileName(filePaths[0]);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the error message you are getting ?

Comment: No specific error message, just unintended behavior. File.Delete is not finding the specified file, and it can be inferred that it's not generating any exception because the image is being moved. The problem is that it should find the old file, because in an earlier method I'm grabbing the name of the old file to pass in to this file.

Comment: Are you sure the `overWrite` variable value is true ?

Comment: Yes, because I declare it as such when calling the method: if (FileManipExtensions.MoveSpecificFiles(filesMove, newDirPath, true)) EDIT: wrong method!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only improvement i can suggest is to use the `Path.Combine` method to generate the correct path. With this method, you do not need to worry about misssing `/` at the end etc.

```
var fullPath = Path.Combine(saveDirectory, fileName);
if (overWrite && File.Exists(fullPath))
{
   File.Delete(fullPath);
}
```

Also since your if condition is checking `overWrite` variable, make sure that the value of `overWrite` is true. I suggest you put visual studio breakpoints and inspect the value of this boolean variable and the `fullPath` variable property.

Also i am not sure what is the value of `saveDirectory` variable. If it is not the full physical file path on the Web server, Consider using [Server.MapPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx) to get that.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: I found the problem, the File.Exists was looking for .jpeg, while the old file was .jpg

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're not missing the slash in the filepath for your if-check?

```
 if (overWrite && File.Exists(saveDirectory + fileName))
```

You might want to try changing your code to be more like:

```
 if (overWrite && File.Exists(saveDirectory + "\\" + fileName))
```

Comment: I've already added the slash in a different method before passing the path in, though I might want to change it so that it looks for a slash at the end before trying to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem. The File.Exists was looking for a .jpeg file, when the original was a .jpg file. Thus, File.Exists didn't find the file, even though the file format was really the same. Just goes to show, check your actual file extensions too!